# Debian cannot see wireless network

Tags: debian, networking, wifi

My WiFi connection just disappeared. I cannot find any network by GUI, but:

```
$ iw wlan0 scan
```

shows nearby networks. Also restarting NetworkManager by few ways (*service ... restart* or `systemctl stop NetworkManager.service` and then disable, enable, start) didn't help.

Using Dell E7440, Debian stretch.

Any ideas?

#### EDIT #1

result of `ip link`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00  
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ec:f4:bb:62:af:80 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  
3: wwp0s20u7c2i12: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:16:26:8b:16:c1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  
4: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 5a:62:db:85:8e:84 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

in `/etc/modprobe.d/` there is no `iwlwifi.conf` file, but just `modsetting.conf`. (Somebody posted a comment about that but now I can't see it...) I had to add those lines to that:

```
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 swcrypto=1
```

I made a backup of `modesetting.conf` and made `iwlwifi.conf` with that commands. Didn't help.

#### EDIT #2

The command:

```
$ nmcli dev status
```

gives me:

```
DEVICE   TYPE     STATE        CONNECTION  
eth0     ethernet connected    eth0  
cdc-wdm1 gsm      disconnected --  
wlan0    wifi     unavailable  --  
lo       loopback unmanaged    --
```

Comment: I've been trying:
> /etc/init.d/networking force-reload  
> service network-manager restart  
> service network-manager force-reload  
  
iw wlan0 scan dump > nothing (with sudo; as user: iw command not found)
results of ip link in main post
Link from wiki: I have no such file, in that folder I can see just: modesetting.conf. Adding proposed line didn't help

Comment: I had much more luck with nmcli than iw/iwconfig, although I never checked the why.